# Simcity worker shortage

Tags: simcity-2013

I got notice by that my worker shortage but when i open this window, all job filled

[image: updated ss]

[image]

What wrong have i done here?

*someone said it because 16 avaiable job
here new screenshot n i still got notice that worker shortage

Comment: you say "all jobs filled" but it says "available jobs - 16", twice.

Comment: 16 is not big deal for that large number

Comment: are you going off opinion, or hard coded game rules?

Comment: Zone more residential and upgrade streets if you haven't already (so they can upgrade and hold even more residents).

Comment: Also, check traffic, they may not be making it to work, add buses and trains (import more jobs) if you can.

Comment: i got no more space for zoning and as u see all avaiable job i 0 but it said worker shortage so i don't know what the problem

Comment: Would need to see your city so see. You can always rezone btw, buldoze things you don't need. You can also import more workers from other cities. But like I also said, transportation can kill you. I had a shortage because of traffic before (plenty of workers, but never making it to work)

Comment: @ydobonebi my buses wait is 26 mins n streetcar is 24 mins, it is green, doesn't it good enough?

Comment: Love this game :) always more problems than solutions. How about trains? Are there anything that needs buldozing?

Comment: @ydobonebi train wait is 34 mins n green

Comment: @ydobonebi i also have drone, doesn't it for better traffic?

Comment: and how many train depo? can you make new city? more cities means more workers

Answer (score 1):

Click on the red triangle and inspect which buildings are closed due to lack of workers.  It is most likely that an insufficient number of workers are reaching a very small number of buildings due to traffic.

Most buildings only need ~40% of job capacity to be filled to open up.  The "good" spectrum of employment ranges (enormously) from ~40% unemployed workers to ~40% unfilled jobs.

I see a large number of commuting workers.  It's generally a bad idea to have extra jobs, as commuting workers are unreliable and buggy.  To fix this, encourage your neighboring cities to provide more jobs.

If traffic is the problem, try a [flux capacitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHmv8.jpg).

Comment: As I mentioned, workers go to work, but sometimes never make it there :) Backtrace the problem or just broadly fix it.